# R can't be installed on Ubuntu 23.10 because libtiff5 is not installable

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-23.10

I try to install R in ubuntu 23.10 but I can't because libtiff5 is installable. This is the message

```
Some packages could not be installed. This can mean that
you requested an impossible situation or, if you are using the
unstable distribution, that some necessary packages have not yet been
created or have been removed from "Incoming".

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
        Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed"
```

have Someone any idea that how can i fix this?

Solution to Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) in ubuntu 23.10

Comment: It seems like there is some conflict or something blocking, this might be in your sources (`/etc/apt/sourced.list.d/*`). Have you tried `apt-get install -y libtiff5` manually?

Comment: Yes. this is the messenge "The libtiff5 package is not available, but some other package references it him. This may mean that the package is missing, obsolete, or only is available from some other source

E: The package "libtiff5" does not have an installation candidate"

But R need libtiff5 and I don´t found alternatives

Comment: While `libtiff5` only goes up to `ubuntu jammy 22.04`, `apt-get install -y libtiff5-dev` gets you to `mantic 23.10`, so you might try that as an approach. And you'll find that having `lib*-dev` is generally always going to be more useful.